# C++ Debug Assertion failed pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I have written a really small program using classes, inheritance, and polymorphism. In main section, I have declared a pointer using new and when I call delete upon it and debug the program, it crashes.

Anyway here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape{
protected:
    int height;
    int width;
public:
    void getVal(int num1, int num2){
        height = num1;
        width = num2;
    }
    int printVal(){
        return (width * height);
    }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape{};

int main(){
    Rectangle rec;
    Shape* shape = new Rectangle;
    shape = &rec;
    shape ->getVal(2,2);
    cout << "Your answer is: " << shape ->printVal() << endl;
    delete shape;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape* shape = new Rectangle;
shape = &rec;
```

You are allocating an object on the heap, then promptly leaking it. `shape` now points to `rec`, an automatic object.

```
delete shape;
```

The object that `shape` currently points to has not been allocated with `new`, so calling `delete` on it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you show me from my code, that would be nice @Igor Tandetnik

Comment: What should I do to be able to call delete on it @Igor Tandetnik

Comment: You should a) drop `Rectangle rec;` and `shape = &rec;` lines, and b) give `Shape` a virtual destructor.